# What kind of transformations can I do on a 2D Voronoi diagram and have it remain valid?

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm a programmer trying to implement a graphical effect using 2D Voronoi diagrams, and I'm wondering what kind of basic geometric transformations I can apply to it while having it still remain a valid Voronoi diagram.

Intuitively, I think I should be able to translate, rotate, reflect and scale it, as long as the scale is uniform along both axes. I can't scale it non-uniformely or shear it. Is that correct?

Comment: that's right; basically you need to preserve the distances between points on the plane (or scale them uniformly).

Comment: Right, of course, that criterion makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what Voronoi diagrams are, but Dima's comment makes me think that your transformations should be from the group ${\mathbb R}^2\rtimes ({\rm O}(2)\times {\mathbb R}^*)$, i.e. all transformations should be a product $T.R.S$ where $T$ is a translation, $R$ is a rotation/reflection, and $S$ is a scalar matrix.

Comment: This question does not appear off-topic.  Perhaps the preamble "I'm a programmer..." led some to this conclusion.  

The question can be understood in one of two senses.  (a) Under what transformations of a set of points and their Voronoi diagram does the transformed VD remain the VD for the transformed set of points?  (b) Under what transformations does a VD remain a VD for some, possibly different, set of points.  It's not obvious to me that the answers to these question must be the same.

Comment: There are certainly (somewhat generic) cases in which non-uniform scaling transforms a point set and its VD in a consistent manner.  For example, Z^n and its VD can be scaled non-uniformly in orthogonal directions and remain consistent.

Another interesting question (though probably not @Oskar's question) might consider which transformations preserve the VD's combinatorial structure.  This does not seem obvious to me, even for the simple case of a lattice.  

If answers to these questions are already known, perhaps the question can be considered merely asking for a reference.

Comment: @Menachem The intention of my question was your version A, that the sites for the diagram should be transformed in the same way as the edges and vertices, while keeping the diagram accurate for those sites, though I agree it's an interesting question. For the combinatorial structure question, do you really think that there's a set of transformations that will preserve an any Voronoi diagrams combinatorial structure, but change the geometric structure? That seems unlikely to me. Then again, I'm not a mathematician.

Comment: Incidentally, I wasn't aware of the distinction between MathOverflow and Math.StackExchange, so I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask. Even so, I do think it's an interesting pure maths question, even if you take my particular use case out of it.

Comment: There is a short non-paper called "The geometry of circles: Voronoi diagrams, Möbius transformations, Convex Hulls, Fortune's algorithm, the cut locus and parametrization of shapes" (maybe it was part of a grant proposal?) in which David Dobkin and Bill Thurston discuss Voronoi diagrams and several related topics.  In it they point out that the combinatorics of the Voronoi diagram are, to large degree, invariant under any Mobius transformation, though such a transformation will change its geometry.